# can't run .scala file from REPL?

Tags: scala, runtime-error

I'm newly at Scala.

I want to run function which is wrote at my file `while.scala`:

```
def whileLoop {
    var i = 1
    while(i <= 3) {
        println(i)
        i += 1
    }
}
whileLoop
```

here is how it looks at REPL:

```
scala> scala /home/nazar/Downloads/while.scala
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
```

If I understood right from book. I need to specify `.scala` file location and run with:

> scala /path/to/file.scala

***Why it fails?***

Here is snippet from book:

```
You can run the code like this:
batate$ scala code/scala/while.scala
1
2
3
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried options `:load` it works, but when I want to run another file `for_loop.scala`:

```
def forLoop {
    println( "for loop using Java-style iteration" )
    for(i <- 0 until args.length) {
        println(args(i))
    }
}    
forLoop
```

it fails:

```
scala> :load /home/nazar/Downloads/for_loop.scala
Loading /home/nazar/Downloads/for_loop.scala...
<console>:9: error: not found: value args
           for(i <- 0 until args.length) {
                            ^
<console>:8: error: not found: value forLoop
              forLoop
              ^

scala> :load /home/nazar/Downloads/for_loop.scala hello scala
That file does not exist
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? That works fine for me in Scala 2.10.4.

Comment: @RandallSchulz `Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0)`

Comment: Re: UPDATE: That's because there's no `args` in the REPL. You only get that for free-standing scripts, either with explicit use of the `scala` command or as shown in the 2nd answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756775/scripting-with-scala-how-to-launch-an-uncompiled-script, as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use command line arguments (via `args`) it is needed to extend `App` or more commonly to define a *principal* or *main* method in an object, namely a `def main(args: Array[String])` method, which defines an entry point to the program. Consider for instance

```
object AnyName extends App {
  def forLoop {
    println( "for loop using Java-style iteration" )
    for(i <- 0 until args.length) {
        println(args(i))
    }
  }
  forLoop
}

AnyName.main(Array("first","second"))
```

Try to load it from REPL. The other approach is thus,

```
object AnyName {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println( "for loop using Java-style iteration" )
    for(i <- 0 until args.length) {
        println(args(i))
    }
  }
}

AnyName.main(Array("first","second"))
```

In this latter example, note the scope of args, bound to the parameter in `main`.

Comment: It's not necessary to extend `App` to get `args` A "naked" Scala script gets them, too.

Answer (score 5):

You do it like this, from the shell / command line, not from within the REPL (`%` is nominal shell prompt):

```
% scala MyScalaScriptName.scala
```

You did this:

```
% scala
scala> scala while.scala
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
```

The only thing known within the Scala REPL is Scala code itself and a few built-in special commands. However, one of them will do what you want:

```
% cd
% scala
scala> :load Downloads/while.scala
Loading Downloads/while.scala
1
2
3
```

Comment: Can you explain more? what is wrong here, and how to solve it? coz I couldn't figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: with load it works. Which ways can I use here to run scala code?

Comment: In the REPL `:load` is your only option. From the command line, you can do as shown above or put a bit of boilerplate into a file header to make a file act as if it's executable (as with other interpreted scripts in the Unix world). The 2nd answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756775/scripting-with-scala-how-to-launch-an-uncompiled-script shows how to do this.

Comment: i updated questions. Can you explain why doesn't work here? It looks the same - Only that I need to specify arguments. But it prints that could't find file....